# Add a blank line between static and non-static imports in Eclipse automatically

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, checkstyle

I want to format my code according to the [Google Java Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3-import-statements).

There are some issues when it comes to [import statements](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3-import-statements). The one rule I can not fulfill other than by manual editing each class is this one:

> If there are both static and non-static imports, a single blank line
>   separates the two blocks.

Apparently, there is no way to configure the `Organize Imports` action in Eclipse to add this blank line.

Are there any workarounds, plugins or plans to add such a feature (or is my only choice to write one myself or use a different IDE)?

Answer (score 9):

It's quite straightforward in Eclipse, here's how to do it:

In "Organize imports" define only two groups:

1. * - all unmatched static imports
2. * - all unmatched type imports

In the formatter set `Blank Lines` → `Blank lines in compilation unit` → `Between import groups` to `1`.

Answer (score 7):

I think this issue is related to the formatter used rather than the `Organize Imports` action per se.

The formatter options are available at `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`. When editing a profile, there's a tab named `Blank Lines` and an option `Between import groups` which you may find useful.

When I have this option set to 1, `Organize Imports` action inserts a blank line between `import` group and `import static` group.

Comment: You're right, but it's adding blank lines after each import **group** as well (java.util, fr, com, ...), which I think is a side effect

Comment: @HBo indeed, unfortunately; but I don't see it as a disadvantage though. I don't think that Eclipse actually distinguishes `import`-`import` space from `import`-`static import` space, but you could [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) in this case as an enhancement.

Comment: nah I'm good, and I'm sure they have more important issues to take care of... seems this is the best way to do it then!

Comment: I'll add a feature request. It's not critical but Google Java Style is quite common and it's annoying if Eclipse doesn't fully support it.